# Should we expect lightning-like phenomena as matter enters the accretion disk of a black hole?

Tags: black-holes, charge, plasma-physics, lightning, accretion-disk

As matter enters the accretion disk it will rapidly turn into superheated plasma. I would expect this to coincide with lightning-like phenomena due to the electric potential difference between this outer edge of the accretion disk and the black hole itself.

The two concerns I have are the high electrical conductivity and turbulence of the accretion disk, which I imagine might be mitigating factors.

Comment: No, lighting happens because the charging occurs in a dielectric media.  Plasmas are highly conductive to the point of being nearly infinitely conductive so charges don't really build up or last long if they do accumulate.